# complex join clause in Laravel Eloquoent

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have three tables: A, B & C.

Table A:

- id
- B_id
- value

Table B:

- id
- C_id
- company

Table C:

- id
- state

Now, I want to do this following query using Eloquoent relationship.

```
select * from A, B, C where A.B_id = B.id and B.C_id = C.id and C.state = 1
```

I decalred the relationships in each model and performed and following query:

```
A::with(['b' => function($query) { 
    $query->with(['C'=> function($q) {
        $q->where('state', 1);
    }]);
}])->get();
```

But, I am not getting the expected result.

What am I missing here?

Comment: post your relationships here.

Comment: We stopped usng comma join syntax ca. 1992 :-(

Comment: What result are you getting? What data is in the database?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `with` with a scope you are only filtering down the relationships, not the top model that you are querying on. You often have to do both a query and a scoped `with`.

Example:

```
A::query()
    ->whereHas('b.c', function ($q) {
        $q->where('state', 1);
    })
    ->with([
        'b.c' => function ($q) {
            $q->where('state', 1);
        },
    ])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
A::join('B', 'B.id', '=', 'A.B_id')
 ->join('C', 'C.id', '=', 'B.C_id')
 ->select(...)
 ->where('C.state', 1)
 ->get();
```

in the **select method** you may specify what field you want to selec of each table, by example:

```
->select('A.*', 'B.company', 'C.state')
```